# Get HDD serial number with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to obtain the value of a client's HDD serial number using ASP.NET?

Comment: On the server? On the client?

Comment: I'm unsure if it's possible. ASP.NET runs on a clients machine physically **but** logically it's on its own platform, isn't it? If you **can** do that, I'd be afraid what more it can see... The contents of my HDD? That would be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
And I'd hope they never implement this. Imagine the security issues with access to such low level information.
Perhaps it is possible using an ActiveX control or some other full-thrust client-side plugin, but not with asp.net itself...